# How to stop logging HTTPGET request Urls in Android logcat?

Tags: android, httpclient, logcat

I am trying to develop an application. I removed all the `Log`s & `System.out.prinln()` from my application.

But, everytime I make a `HTTPGet` request, then logcat is displaying my request URL.

How to stop this ? I dont want to expose these urls. This is how its printing in the `Logcat`

```
02-24 22:09:39.492    1566-1600/com.pushdemo.sample I/System.out﹕ httpget:http://samplewebsite.com/postnotify/humanity.xml
02-24 22:09:39.492    1566-1600/com.pushdemo.sample I/System.out﹕ http://samplewebsite.com/postnotify/curiosity.xml
02-24 22:09:39.506    1566-1619/com.pushdemo.sample I/System.out﹕ httpget:http://samplewebsite.com/postnotify/simplicity.xml
02-24 22:09:39.506    1566-1619/com.pushdemo.sample I/System.out﹕ http://samplewebsite.com/postnotify/enemity.xml
```

This is my code for fetching data from server XML file.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200) 
        {   
            String result=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            byte ptext[]=result.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
            connListener.status(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            connListener.response(value);
            return value;

        }
```

Comment: class 'com.pushdemo.sample' has a Log.i  statements in it .. change those

Comment: @RobertRowntree.. It's coming on few devices. This is the only code in that class.